# GitLab:Merge Request: If multiple MR into Develop but move only my changes to QA branch

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

There are multiple Merge requests merged into Develop but I want to MR only my changes  from develop branch to the QA branch

```
 /abc/abc.py  ---|
 /abc/deg.py  ---|Changes merged into develop by other developer 
 /test.py     ---|
 /tss/tss.py  ---|Changes merged into develop by me **( I want only these to move to next branch)**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `cherry-pick` to resolve the issue by selecting only the changes/commit you want to apply.

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.